# Django - get auto_now field in pre_save signal

Tags: python, django, signals

I'm using Django 2.1.5.

There is a model with 'auto_now' field:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now=True)
    updated_by = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    responded_at = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, null=True, blank=True)
    responded_by = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

Now, I have a `pre_save` signal for that model, and I want to update there the `responded_at` and `responded_by` fields to be equal to `updated_at` and `updated_by`. In that signal - the `updated_by` value is already the new one, as supposed to be in the end of the request, but the `updated_at` is not. It's the old (current) value.
I want, if possible, to be able to get the value that supposed to be in `updated_at` field after the save.

The reason I'm using `pre_save` signal and not `post_save` is because I'm updating the instance inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Since your are using `auto_now` with your `updated_at` field, it will inherit `editable=False` and `blank=True`.

As the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) state:

> As currently implemented, setting auto_now or auto_now_add to True will cause the field to have editable=False and blank=True set.

To avoid this, you can write a custom field like this:

```
from django.utils import timezone


class AutoDateTimeField(models.DateTimeField):
    def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        return timezone.now()
```

You can use this in your `BaseModel` like this:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    updated_at = models.AutoDateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    # ...
```

This way the `updated_at` field should be editable and your signal should work.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want to get the value of `updated_at` as if I'm in post_save and put it in `responded_at`. I don't want to edit `updated_at`

Comment: If you want to get the value of `updated_at` and save it in your `responded_at` field whenever a `BaseModel` object is changed, I dont see why you would not want to create a custom field that inherits from `DateTimeField` in order to make your signal work?